# How to assign a cString to a structure variable only IF a condition is true C++?

Tags: c++, structure

I have a program reading in employee information from a text file and storing it into a structure. I also have an enum with `F` representing full-time employee and `P` representing part-time employee. If the employee is full-time, I deduct $5 from their pay for union dues. The text file is as follows:
[image: input]

Here is my structure and enum:

```
 enum EmpType{
      F, P
 };

struct EmpData{
     char* name;
     float payrate;
     float hours;
     EmpType employee_type;
     double pay;
     char deductions[];
};
```

I need to print out "Union dues deducted" if $5 has been deducted from the employee's pay. I assume I need some sort of `if` statement that prints it out if dues are deducted and doesn't do anything when fees haven't been deducted. and this is what I have so far. I've tried assigning deductions to a pointer and changing the types but I just can't wrap my head around what to do. When I try to assign "Union dues deducted" to employee deductions it says "expression must be a modifiable value".

```
employee[entries]->pay = employee[entries]->payrate * employee[entries]->hours; // calculating pay

if (employee[entries]->employee_type == F)
{
    employee[entries]->pay = employee[entries]->pay - 5;
}
if (employee[entries]->pay == employee[entries]->pay - 5)
{
    employee[entries]->deductions = // code goes here?
}
```

Thank you for any help. This is my first post so please let me know if this isn't clear or anything.
Here is what the output should look like (I have everything working but deductions): [image: output]

Comment: I believe somewhere you need to assign the memory for deductions although you would need to more research on flexible array members for the exact usage of them.

I would suggest  std::string or something similar to store your string values, it should make things a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error "expression must be a modifiable value" is confusing for me.

Declare the size for the static array. i.e., deductions in structure EmpData. 
Then use strcpy to copy "Union dues deducted" into deductions.

```
strcpy (employee[entries]->deductions, "Union dues detected");
```